# How TypeScript union types on that occasion

Tags: typescript, overloading

Hello I'm creating a function inside a class called Point that sum the value of X and Y with Point or X and Y parameters.

Example:

```
public Offset(dx: number, dy: number) {
    this.X += dx;
    this.Y += dy;
}

public OffsetPoint(p: Point) {
    this.X += p.X;
    this.Y += p.Y;
}
```

Instead of creating two functions, creating only one, is it possible with typescript?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no right way. But a small hack exists:

```
class Point {
    X: number
    Y: number

    constructor(X: number, Y: number) {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public Offset(dx : number | Point , dy? : number) {
        if (dy) {
          this.X += dx as number;
          this.Y += dy as number;
        } else {
          let p = dx as Point;
          this.X += p.X;
          this.Y += p.Y;
        }
    }
}

let a = new Point(1, 1);
let b = new Point(2, 2)

console.log('a.x', a.X, 'a.y', a.Y); // "a.x",  1,  "a.y",  1 
a.Offset(b)
console.log('a.x', a.X, 'a.y', a.Y); // "a.x",  3,  "a.y",  3 
a.Offset(10, 20)
console.log('a.x', a.X, 'a.y', a.Y); // "a.x",  13,  "a.y",  23
```